# SwiftUI - Date Picker not showing correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I´ve created a DatePicker element in SwiftUI, but the DatePicker opens inside the view instead of a sheet at the bottom. (Screenshot below)

[image]

**My code:**

```
@ObservedObject private var report = Report(
    id: 0,
    timestamp: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 118800),
    date: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 118800),
)


Section(header: Text("Allgemeine Daten")) {
    HStack {
        Label(string: "Name")
        Divider()
        TextField("Name", text: $person.name)
    }
    HStack {
        Label(string: "Monat")
        Divider()
        DatePicker(selection: $report.date, displayedComponents: .date) {
            Text("Select a date")
        }

    }
}
```

The Section is inside a NavigationView and Form. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's actually getting temporarily added to the view hierarchy where your `DatePicker` is. Since your date picker is in an `HStack`, it gets appended to the end of the `HStack` resulting in what you see. If you add the `DatePicker` by itself, then it gets added to the `Section` instead, and will shift content below. It's still a pretty terrible animation/user experience, though, so I have to assume it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So actually there is no possibility to open the DatePicker in a sheet on the bottom of the page?